# how to build faceted navigation by php for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I would like to create auto inject sub-query.

here is the example:

my code will begin with this query

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM  ecom_products_selected_features_values 
WHERE  feature_value_id  in (9)
```

and I have array with number

```
$numbers = array(6,5)
```

i would like to create on run time below query

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM  ecom_products_selected_features_values 
WHERE  feature_value_id  in (9) AND product_id in (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM  ecom_products_selected_features_values 
    WHERE  feature_value_id in (6) AND  product_id in (
        SELECT product_id 
        FROM  ecom_products_selected_features_values 
        WHERE  feature_value_id  in (5))
)
```

Comment: So, you want to replace the 9 with 6 and then with 5? It is a bit hard to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: sorry i delete the example by mistake i would like to create query like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to do subqueries. They are slow - especially for large data sets. You want to join. This is what I would do:

```
$query = '
    select a.productid
    from ecom_products_selected_features_values a
';
```

That is the base of the query. Now, I loop through your array:

```
foreach($numbers as $i=>$n)
    $query.= "
        join ecom_products_selected_features_values b$i
        on a.productid=b$i.productid
        and b$i.feature_value_id in ($n)
    ";
```

That appends a join for each number. Each join has a unique ID based on the array key value. But, we haven't limited to the 9 yet. Add that on:

```
$query.= 'where a.feature_value_id in (9)';
```

The result query will be:

```
select a.product_id
from eps a
join eps b0
on a.productid=b0.productid
and b0.feature_value_id in (6)
join eps b1
on a.productid=b1.productid
and b1.feature_value_id in (5)
where a.feature_value_id in (9)
```

Of course, why use in? It is slow. I would change those to feature_value_id=$n.

Comment: Is that like faceted navigation if yes you making my day

Comment: Yes. It can be used for that. You will notice that each join is really just a filter on the original set. So, as you add filters, you limit the data set. If this is used for content in a website, it is faceted navigation.